How do I ensure that roles are assigned correctly during the login process?
In my Next.js project I am developing an application that handles two types of users, therapists and users. I use NextAuth to allow login with Google (this only has the role of user), but an interesting problem arises: when I try to log in with a created test account, the system is not taking the role of therapist the user i crate is this const user = {id: "1", name: "user", email: "uss@mail.com", password: "12345", role: "therapist"}, which should restrict your access to the users dashboard. How can I solve that?
i'm using this tutorial for assigning and verifying roles, the only changes are the following:
in /api/auth/[...nexauth]/route.ts :
const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [ GoogleProvider ({
        profile(profile: GoogleProfile){
            //console.log(profile) -> Ver perfil en consola 
            return{
                ...profile,
                rol: "usuario", //profile.rol ??
                id: profile.sub,
            }
        },
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,

        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            //id: 'credentials',
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
              email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
              password: { label: "Password", type: "text" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) { //credentials: any
                //Ejemplo para conocer si funciona
              const user = {id: "1", name: "isabel", email: "isa@mail.com", password: "12345", rol: "terapeuta"}
                if(credentials?.email === user.email && credentials?.password === user.password){
                    return user;
              }else{
                return null;
              }
 },
          })
    ],
callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }){
            if(user) token.rol = user.rol
            return token
        },
        //usar el rol en componentes de cliente
        async session({ session, token}){
            if(session?.user) session.user.rol = token.rol
            return session
        }
 }
});
export {handler as GET, handler as POST};

In app/middleware.ts is added:
export default withAuth(
    // 'withAuth augments your 'request' with the user's token
    function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth){
        console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname)
        console.log(request.nextauth.token)

        if(request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboardU") 
        && request.nextauth.token?.rol !== "usuario"){
            return NextResponse.rewrite(
                new URL("/signin", request.url)
            )
        }
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized: ({ token }) => !!!token
        },
    }
    
)
export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard", "/admin", "/dashboard_U", "/dashboard_tera", "/signin", "/singup"] }

In the tutorial I followed I created the next-auth-d.ts file that contains:
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from "next-auth";
import {JWT, DefaultJWT} from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface Session{
        user: {
            id: string,
            rol: string,
        } & DefaultSession
    }
    interface User extends DefaultUser{
        rol: string,
    }
}
declare module "next-auth/jwt"{
    interface JWT extends DefaultJWT {
        rol: string,
    }
}

in /signin you only have this to be able to send the form data to route.ts:
const router = useRouter();
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    // const session = useSession();
    const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
        router.replace("/dashboardU"); //"/dashboard"
        }
    }, [sessionStatus, router]);

    const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target[0].value;
        const password = e.target[1].value;

        const res = await signIn('credentials', {
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false,
        });

And here is the form for signin in te app
form className="flex flex-col items-center w-full" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                                 
                                <input type="email" className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Correo"/>
                                <br />
                                <input type="password" className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
                            
                                <CustomButton/>
                            </form>```

